# what is the wrong in this MySQL command?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query in MySQL

```
SELECT  *,(select lat from node where id=node_id)as lat,(select lng from node where id=node_id)as lng from tag,node WHERE 1 limit 5
```

but i get this error message ..

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

what's the problem ??

Comment: The error message does not match the code you posted. You do not have `''` in the SQL statement but the error messages refers to single quotes. Additionally you are creating a cartesian product between 'tag' and 'node'. Are you sure you want that? And why do you use the dumb `WHERE 1`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: these single quotes are a default part of MySQL error message. Try running `SELECT * FROM;`

Comment: Regular MySQL nonsense. How can anyone still be using it after such error messages?

Comment: what do you think the correct query, i want to retrieve data from tag table where it has node_id column, and i want to retrieve the corresponding lat,lng columns from node table

Comment: @AlexanderMP: I guess anyone who knows, that it means the syntax is wrong at the end of line 1.

Comment: @Mchl, the thing is I got the same error pointing at a line which was 100% correct, and the code was about 600 lines long. Since then I had no desire to ever deal with crappy software like MySQL. That time I had to divide and conquer, until I found the error.

Comment: @AlexanderMP: I would very much like to see the code that confused you so much. Did the error involve a missing quote by any chance?

Comment: @Mchl, that was a year ago, on a server I don't have access to any more. It was something like a semicolon or an error in a conditional statement. I don't remember well. That's the biggest thing I ever did on MySQL. Since then I only work with it if I have no alternative, and keep on getting very uninformative errors, but because the code is shorter, they are easier to find. Of all the RDBMS I worked with, only FirebirdSQL and Microsoft SQL Server returned adequate information on errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to:

- Specify a valid `WHERE` clause, which would contain a boolean expression, or don't use one at all.
- Use full field names (`lat.id`, `lat.node_id`? ) or something
- Use unique aliases for tables (you are using 2 different sets of `node` twice in a single scope - inside the subqueries)

Generally - write a more comprehensive, and specific query, which allows no ambiguity and no trouble.

> i want to retrieve data from tag table
>   where it has node_id column, and i
>   want to retrieve the corresponding
>   lat,lng columns from node table

```
SELECT
    tag.*,
    node.lat,
    node.lng
FROM
    tag
JOIN node ON tag.node_id=node.id
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what you're looking for is this. This code is equivalent to "Show me the first 5 rows from tag and the corresponding columns 'lat' and 'lng' from node where node_id in tag equals node_id in node"

```
SELECT tag.*, node.lat, node.lng
FROM tag JOIN node ON tag.node_id=node.node_id
LIMIT 1,5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT  tag.*, node.*,
  (select lat from node where id=node_id)as lat,
  (select lng from node where id=node_id)as lng 
from tag,node 
WHERE 1 limit 5
```

this however will be very inefficient, as it uses two correlated subqueries and no JOIN condition. Perhaps you could explain what you want to achieve, and we could improve this query?

Answer (score 1):

Ok there are so many poor coding techniques in that I'm not sure where to start.

First, did you mean to have a cross join becasue that is what you have. It is a very bad practice to use implicit joins in writing sql code. IT leads to mistakes and it is harder to maintain. You would not write C# or Java code that had been replaced with someting better in 1992 would you?

select * is a very bad choice. Always explicitly define what columns you need.

What are you tyring to get at with WHERE 1? That doesn't make sense.

ANd generally correlated subqueries are bad. Why are you not just doing an inner join and then selecting the fields?

Comment: "select * is a very bad choice. Always explicitly define what columns you need. " +1, forgot to mention that.